# Swift: Full screen UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

Using Swift, I want to click a smaller image view which then expands to full screen of the device and once clicked again to go back to the default size it was before.

This is the code I have but when clicked it doesn't expand to full screen more as in, it expands to the views width.

I have a pop up UIView on top of my main view to show as a pop up and the image expands to that pop up view but not the whole screen.

Before clicking imageView
[image: image1]

After clicking imageVjew
[image]

How would I achieve a full screen of my imageView?

```
@IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var popUpView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var iconImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    iconImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

@IBAction func handleTap(_ gesutureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    iconImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
}
```

Comment: subview will be with in superview bound, if the immediate superview is not full screen, then how can subview?

Comment: Why is `handleTap(_:)` an `@IBAction` if you are creating it in code? Change `@IBAction` to `@objc` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: try calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on `iconImage` after you change its frame

Comment: What Content Mode are you using for your image view? Scale to Fill? Aspect Fill? Aspect Fit?

Comment: Even if you solve this problem (I'm sure that you will, it doesn't seem to me a hard), imageView will change its frame with no animation, it's not the best user experience. Try to change iconImage frame animating - you can do it with changing autolayout constraints or animate frame directly.

Comment: @rishi what? the pop up view is smaller than the backgroundView.

Comment: @BradleyMackey no difference in that

Comment: @DonMag Aspect Fit but its within the bounds of the popUp view so its not full screen

Comment: @TNguyen what is `layoutIfNeeded`?

Comment: @BroSimple forces view to update its layout if there's any updates pending

Comment: @TNguyen just an error, no function with that exist

Comment: @BroSimple that's weird, did you do `iconImage.layoutIfNeeded()` ?

Comment: @TNguyen nothing changed, the image is still stuck within the bounds of the pop up view

Comment: instead of `UIScreen.main.bounds` can you try `self.view.bounds` or `self.view.frame` (this is assuming that the view of the controller takes up the whole screen)

Comment: @TNguyen i tried all of that including `self.backgroundView.bounds`/`frame` and nothing. Still within the bounds of the pop up view. backgroundView takes the whole screen, I have another view on top of that, which is way smaller.

Comment: can you share with us your view hiearchy/image of your storyboard items ?

Comment: @TNguyen I added my screen view to the post

Comment: the problem could be the way the constraints are setup. Set the view to not clip to bounds and be sure that you dont have a constraint on the `width = height` or else it will resize the height to be the width of the view (you might not have set it up this way but its just my intuition seeing as that is an icon that would most likely always want to be a square)

Comment: @TNguyen the only constraints I have is for the pop up view not for the imageView, would it still affect it?

Comment: you have no constraints set on the imageView at all?

Comment: @TNguyen no constraints on imageView just the pop up view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155783/discussion-between-tnguyen-and-brosimple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the logic of this tutorial, but instead of creating a UIViewController for the "popup" you can create an UIViewController with an imageView in fullscreen mode.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgCIRMz_3dE&t=430s

Comment: Yeah thats true I can just create another view controller to simulate a full screen for the imageView. I thought there was a more simple way